# Should bash scripts use sudo, or assume sudo?

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, sudo

Which pattern is preferable:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Installing blah
apt-get install -y blah
```

...which will fail if run without root perms, or:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Installing blah
sudo apt-get install -y blah
```

...which will succeed as long as the user has sudo access.

I have tended to use the second pattern, but it seems to be rare, so I'm asking what its disadvantages are. The benefits I see are:

- It's clear which commands actually require superuser permissions to run (useful if the reader wants to pull the script apart)
- Saves a few keystrokes for the user.

I guess downsides include that the use of root permissions might be surprising ("I didn't type `sudo`, so I didn't expect anything like apt-get to be run...."). What else?

Comment: What if do it in a little bit more complicated way? First you can check `id` of a user. Or you can run `apt-get install -y blah` and if it fails ask a user if to run as sudo?

Comment: It's a sad fact that the correct approach to most shell scripting problems *is* rare.

Comment: There is many argument in favor of using `sudo`. However, AFAIK, `sudo` isn't part of the base system. Using it in your script will require the user to install (and potentially _configure_) that optional software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option is the correct option. Commands that don't require root access should not be run as root just to simplify your script. Commands that do require root access (or access by any specific user, for that matter) should be run by sudo. For clarity, you can use the `-p` option to `sudo` to present a custom prompt which can explain exactly why the user is asked for their password.

Option two is also preferable because `sudo` is highly configurable, and the user may already have permission to run specific commands with `sudo` *without* a password, so it's possible the user would not be inconvenienced by a password prompt. It's less likely that the user is allowed to `sudo` arbitrary commands (such as your script) without a password.

Answer (score 2):

I will prefer second Pattern,
because running few commands with sudo is better rather then running entire script with root  permissions in which some commands are needless to have root access and so if you perform these commands with root user further using that command outputs will again need root access or you will have to change the ownership. 
So I will prefer second approach where sudo is necessary do it, else go local user.

Comment: +1 Only the commands that *need* to run as root should. In the OP's case, suppose the system is configured to automatically let the user run `apt-get` as root without a password, but not allow any other command via `sudo`. Option 1 prevents the user from running the script at all; option 2 lets the user run the script and doesn't require a password.

Answer (score 2):

You could always test if the user is root (`id -u` gets the uid of the current user, and 0 is root), and run `sudo` if they aren't -

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Installing blah
CMD=""
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
  CMD="sudo"
fi
${CMD} apt-get install -y blah
```

The more common approach would be to exit with an error condition if they aren't root,

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
  echo "sudo $0 (must run as root)"
  exit 1
fi
echo Installing blah
apt-get install -y blah
```

Comment: The first option is pointless, since `sudo` is essentially a no-op for root&mdash;just hard-code `sudo` where needed. The second option ignores the main issue of running more commands than necessary as root.